# polars groupby use equal weighted average when sum of weights is zero

Tags: group-by, null, mean, python-polars, weighted-average

I want to calculate the weighted average of a polars dataframe during a groupby operation. If the sum of the weights within the groupby equal zero I want to return the equally weighted mean. Additionally, I want to ignore null values in the columns to average or the weight columns.

Notation:

```
df (polars.DataFrame): input dataframe
gr (list[str]): columns to groupby
vr (list[str]): columns to take average of
wt (str): column to use as the weights
```

To calculate the equally weighted average I have

```
res = df.group_by(gr, maintain_order = True).agg(polars.col(vr).mean())
```

By default mean function ignores null values in the 'vr' columns, which is desired.

To calculate the weighted average I have

```
mask_wt = polars.col(wt) * polars.col(vr).is_not_null()
wavg = (polars.col(vr) * polars.col(wt)).sum() / mask_wt.sum()
res = df.group_by(gr, maintain_order = True).agg(wavg)
```

Masking the weights allows me to ignore null values in 'vr' columns and the 'wt' column.

For example,

```
import polars

df = polars.DataFrame({'id': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'y'], 
                       'dt': ['j', 'f', 'j', 'f'],
                       'a': [None, 2, 3, 4], 
                       'b': [5, 6, 7, 8], 
                       'wt': [1, 0, 0.25, 0.25]})

gr = ['id']
vr = ['a', 'b']
wt = 'wt'

>>> df
┌─────┬─────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ id  ┆ dt  ┆ a    ┆ b   ┆ wt   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ str ┆ str ┆ i64  ┆ i64 ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ x   ┆ j   ┆ null ┆ 5   ┆ 1.0  │
│ x   ┆ f   ┆ 2    ┆ 6   ┆ 0.0  │
│ y   ┆ j   ┆ 3    ┆ 7   ┆ 0.25 │
│ y   ┆ f   ┆ 4    ┆ 8   ┆ 0.25 │
└─────┴─────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘

>>> df.group_by(gr, maintain_order = True).agg(polars.col(vr).mean())
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ id  ┆ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ x   ┆ 2.0 ┆ 5.5 │
│ y   ┆ 3.5 ┆ 7.5 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘

>>> mask_wt = polars.col(wt) * polars.col(vr).is_not_null()
>>> wavg = (polars.col(vr) * polars.col(wt)).sum() / mask_wt.sum()
>>> res = df.group_by(gr, maintain_order = True).agg(wavg)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ id  ┆ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ x   ┆ NaN ┆ 5.0 │
│ y   ┆ 3.5 ┆ 7.5 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I would like the NaN in the weighted average to be replaced with the 2 from the equally weighted average because when ignoring the weight for the null value in the column 'a' the sum of the weights is 0, so the equally weighted average should be returned.

Using pandas I can accomplish this by

```
import pandas

def _wavg_py(gr, vr, wt):
    x = gr[[vr, wt]].dropna()
    den = x[wt].sum()
    if(den == 0):
        return(gr[vr].mean())
    else:
        return((x[vr] * x[wt]).sum() / den)

res = df.groupby(by = gr).apply(_wavg_py, col, wt)
```

Comment: Can you fix your example? `a` has `None, None` in the data but you show a single `null` in the dataframe repr. The values for `gr, vr, wt` are also missing.

Comment: Fixed those typos, thank you for looking at the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is an acceptable approach to
[`.fill_nan()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.fill_nan.html#polars.Expr.fill_nan) with the `.mean()`

```py
df.group_by(gr, maintain_order=True).agg(
    wavg.fill_nan(pl.col(vr).mean())
)
```

```py
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ id  ┆ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ x   ┆ 2.0 ┆ 5.0 │
│ y   ┆ 3.5 ┆ 7.5 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Alternatively, it seems you're asking how to perform conditional logic inside expressions

i.e.
[`when/then/otherwise`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html#polars.when)

```py
df.group_by(gr, maintain_order=True).agg(
    pl.when(pl.col('wt').filter(pl.col(vr).is_not_null()).sum() == 0)
      .then(pl.col(vr).mean())
      .otherwise(wavg)
)
```

```py
shape: (2, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ id  ┆ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ x   ┆ 2.0 ┆ 5.0 │
│ y   ┆ 3.5 ┆ 7.5 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: The when/then/otherwise was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!